# PHP $_SESSION[variable] Always Equals Same Thing

Tags: php, session

I don't have much experience with php or sql so I may be missing something really basic. My main goal is that if a first file is visited and then a second file is visited you will be able to access that second file. However if you don't visit the first file you are denied access. I have an HTML file which is meant to set `$_SESSION[upgrade]` to 1. I use accountify and it "extends php's session support" so this might be a accountify related question. Also a session is already running because of accountify. ([Link To Accountify](http://www.boutell.com/accountify/)) This is the complete file:

```
<?php
require '/home/u760887416/public_html/accountify/login.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['upgrade'])) {
  $_SESSION['upgrade'] = 1; 
};
echo("<p>You were upgraded. <br>Redirecting...</p>");
//this is a test:
if($_SESSION['upgrade'] = 1) {
  echo("<p>complete</p>");
  };
?>
```

After it is set to 1, in a different file I want if `$_SESSION['upgrade'] = 1` then it loads some code. Here is the code:

```
<?php
  require '/home/u760887416/public_html/accountify/login.php';
  if($login->loggedIn AND $_SESSION['upgrade'] = 1) {
?>
//code to run...
<?php
  } else { 
?>
//more code to run
<?php
  } 
?>
```

The problem is that after I load the first file and go to the second (it doesn't matter if I reset the session, create a new one or use a different computer) it always runs the `else` code. I've spent way too much time on this and can't figure it out. Please tell me if I did not supply enough information to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `==` instead of `=` in your if statements.
Using `=` SETS the value of  `$_SESSION['upgrade']` to 1, not compares it to 1.

Change if declaration of your first file like that:

```
if($_SESSION['upgrade'] == 1) {
  echo("<p>complete</p>");
  };
```

Also I recommend using `&&` instead of `AND` operator. Your if in the second file should look like this:

```
if($login->loggedIn && $_SESSION['upgrade'] == 1) {
?>
//code to run...
<?php
  } else { 
?>
//more code to run
<?php
  } 
?>
```